# Recursively printing string backwards, increment each time

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, recursion, reverse

I have this function here that will print a string until it gets to the last character. The thing is I need it to do the opposite of that.

Instead of 'abc' printing 'abc, ab, c' I need it to print 'c, bc, abc'.

Thank you!

```
def reverse(string):
  if len(string) == 0:
    return string
  else:
    print(string)
    return reverse(string[1:])
```

Comment: You might have to use a list to keep the strings and then print it later.

Answer (score 2):

Just switch the 2 lines in the else. This will cause all of the recursive calls to happen *before* any of the `print` statements. Once the end of the string is reached, the recursion will unwind and all the `print`s will happen:

```
def reverse(string):
    if not string:
        return
    else:
        reverse(string[1:])
        print(string)

reverse("abc")
```

Output:

```
c
bc
abc
```

Answer (score 1):

The base case here is easy: the length of the string is 0, simply return without printing. If it isn't the base case, you have two things to do, keep breaking the string down (*recursively*), or printing the string. Depending on the order, you can get the results *printed in a different order*:

```
>>> def rev(string):
...     if string:
...         rev(string[1:]) # keep breaking down the string
...         print(string) # print the string
...         return
...     else:
...         return
...
>>> rev('abc')
c
bc
abc
```

Now look if we switch:

```
>>> def rev(string):
...     if string:
...         print(string) # print the string
...         rev(string[1:]) # keep breaking down the string
...         return
...     else:
...         return
...
>>> rev('abc')
abc
bc
c
```

Note, you don't really need the `else: return`, or the `return` after at the end of the `if` block, but I kept it in just to be explicit and make you think about what is happening in your function.

Think of yourself as the first, intended version of the function. I receive a string as an argument, and it isn't empty. I then create a duplicate of myself (since we are imagining things) then break down my string and hand it off to him, giving him "control". And he does the same thing: checks if the string is not empty, breaks it down if that is the case, and creates a clone and gives him the new string and control, all the way down until we reach a clone who receives an empty string. This clone simply checks and sees that the string is empty, and *returns* control to the clone that called him. This clone now does the next step: he *prints*, and this clone is the clone that got a string with length one... after he is done printing, he *returns control* to the clone that called him...

Comment: @user633183 it does, maybe you didn't notice that there were two versions

Comment: my mistake; deleting my previous comment to avoid confusing future readers.